# Automatically logging into website and scraping data with python

Tags: string, python-2.7, ubuntu, mechanize, autologin

I am making a Python program to display wind speeds off a website that I have an account with, so that I don’t have to log in and check the winds manually. 
So far this is some of the code

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)

response = br.open("http://example.com/login")

br.select_form('save_key') #form name 

br.form['login']='myusername'

br.form['password']='mypassword'

response=br.submit()

response = br.retrieve("http://example.com/wind")[0] #get the html code
```

That works fine, but the problem is getting the data off the site where only members can access using that code. I can save the html file but I don't know how to sort through the code to get the data (it's not the best html) and I don’t think saving html files and sorting through them every time is very efficientD oes anyone know how I could scrape the data off and still stay logged in? If you try without logging in you just get the login page html.

An example of the html (terrible code):

```
<TR><TD colspan='8' align='center' bgcolor='#55840A'><font color='#FFFFFF'>D A Y S&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;R E C O R D S</font></TD></TR><TR align='left'><TD><font color='#FFFFFF'>Wind Gust:</font></TD><TD><fontclass='numbers'>24</font> <font class='units'>km/h</font></TD><TD><font color='#FFFFFF'>Min Temperature:</font></TD><TD><font class='numbers'>8.8</font> <font class='units'>&deg;C</font></TD><TD><fontcolor='#FFFFFF'>Max Temperature:</font></TD><TD><font class='numbers'>19.3</font> <font class='units'>&deg;C</font></TD><TD><font color='#FFFFFF'>High:</font></TD><TD><font class='numbers'>31</font></TD></TR><TR><TD colspan='2'></TD><TD><font color='#FFFFFF'>Min Humidity:</font></TD><TD><font class='numbers'>67</font> <font class='units'>%</font></TD><TD><font color='#FFFFFF'>Max Humidity:</font></TD><TD><font class='numbers'>96</font> <font class='units'>%</font></TD><TD colspan='2'></TD></TR></TABLE>
```

So for example the Min Temperature is 8.8

```
<TD><font color='#FFFFFF'>Min Temperature:</font></TD><TD><font class='numbers'>8.8</font> <font class='units'>&deg;C</font></TD>
```

which makes it hard to scrape data off.

Comment: Do they have REST/JSON or SOAP API? Do they return "403" status code for unsuccessfull login?

Comment: I dont know the API but It does return 403 for  unsuccessful login

Comment: You could use HTTP status to check auth result, but working with HTML instead of REST API is pain, anyway. Consider obtaining REST or SOAP access to this service

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are going to want to use regular expressions against the returned HTML for the values you want. I recommend using [Pythex](http://pythex.org/) to test the regex.

For example, try using the following regex:

```
Min Temperature:</font></TD><TD><font class='numbers'>(\d+.\d*)
```

In the "Your regular expression:" and include the full html response in the "Your test string:" field and you will get the value you want.

Comment: Thanks Pythex works but is their anyway to install the module so that I can add that to my code ?